# Retrofit - android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException with RxKotlin

Tags: android, android-viewmodel, flatmap, rx-kotlin

I've created rx function to call a network call from `view-model` in android, it parses network on main thread function.

I just change few line of code it worked. but i need to know the reason for this because its use same builder pattern to create a `rx-call`.
once I tried with changing `.doOnSubscribe()` ,`doOnComplete ()`           , `.applySchedulers()` after the flatmap call it worked? how is  this happened?

```
fun loadjobs(var countryID:String){
subscription.add(
repository.getMainJobsFromLocal(countryID)
          .doOnSubscribe { postProgress(StatusModel(Status.IN_PROGRESS))}
          .doOnComplete { postProgress(StatusModel(Status.COMPLETED)) }
          .applySchedulers()
          .flatMap {
           if (it.isNullOrEmpty()) {
              repository.getMainJobsFromServer(countryID)
           } else {
              Flowable.just(Response.success(it))
           }
          }
          .subscribe({
            if (it.isResponseOk()) {
             postProgress(StatusModel(Status.SUCCESS))
             mainJobResponse.postValue(it.body())
           } else {
             postProgress(StatusModel(Status.FAILED))
             mainJobResponse.postValue(null)
           }
          }, {
           postProgress(StatusModel(Status.FAILED))
           mainJobResponse.postValue(null)
        }))
}


fun loadjobs(var countryID){
subscription.add(
repository.getMainJobsFromLocal(countryID)
          .flatMap {
           if (it.isNullOrEmpty()) {
             repository.getMainJobsFromServer(countryID).flatMap {
               Flowable.just(it)
             }
           } else {
             Flowable.just(Response.success(it))
           }
          }.doOnSubscribe { postProgress(StatusModel(Status.IN_PROGRESS)) }
            .doOnComplete { postProgress(StatusModel(Status.COMPLETED)) }
            .applySchedulers()
            .subscribe({
              if (it.isResponseOk()) {
                postProgress(StatusModel(Status.SUCCESS))
                mainJobResponse.postValue(it.body())
               } else {
               postProgress(StatusModel(Status.FAILED))
               mainJobResponse.postValue(null)
              }
           }, {
            postProgress(StatusModel(Status.FAILED))
            mainJobResponse.postValue(null)
    }))
}
```

Comment: The `applyScheduler()` is not going to make the whole  observable streams to go async. Every time you invoke a network request you should chain it with this function.

Comment: Tell me which of these functions are supposed to be async in another thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> applySchedulers() after the flatmap call it worked? how is this happened?

`observeOn()` affects everything downstream. If you have a `flatMap()` after `observeOn()`, it gets executed on that scheduler.

Similarly `subscribeOn()` affects the upstream chain.

For these reasons, for most use cases you'd want to have the schedulers applied at the end of your rx chain and not in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

Add `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` and `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` to your Observable.

Comment: this two are sets with the .applySchedulers() its a extention function.

fun <T> Flowable<T>.applySchedulers(): Flowable<T> {
    return subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
}